# Dotnetnuke 6.2 Editing User and Role module

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I'd like to inject some code after user registration. I've find code in Admin/Security/ManagerUsers  cmdRegister_Click method.

But to successively run my code I need to compile this module. How could I do this, since there's no .csproj for this module ?

Thanks for replay, I really need this to work properly and run out of ideas how to solve this..
I'm using the latest community version of dnn.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the dnn source package if you want to change the core, but...
It might not be the best idea to change the dnn core, if you ever want to upgrade you need to re-do the changes. 
Depending on your needs you could buy a third party module (i.e. dynamic registration from datasprings). This module is able to run any kind of sql script or do redirection to a page and the like.